# How to pass the error IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am extracting the data from a csv using ILOC from pandas. When I want to extract the text of a column and row where there is nothing, it just throws me this error:
IndexError: single positional indexer is out of bounds

I know perfectly why this error appears, but I want that in the place of error I simply do not put anything or something similar.

Is there any way that when I try to extract the text from an empty cell it gives me a none, a 0 or something like that?

This is the code by the way:

```
        products = pd.read_csv("priv/products.csv")
        product_1 = products.iloc[0,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just stick it in a try block. If you find that clutters up your code you can make a helper function.

```py
def tryloc(df, col, idx, default=None):
  try:
    return df.iloc[col, idx]
  except IndexError:
    return default

products = pd.read_csv("priv/products.csv")
product_1 = tryloc(products, 0, 1)
```

Comment: ok but I get this error now: NameError: the name 'df' is not defined

Comment: I edited my answer. You just need to pass your DataFrame as the first argument, which is named `products`. I had it written as `df` which was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error. Per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) you can only pass the following as inputs to `iloc`:

> .iloc[] is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

> Allowed inputs are:

> An integer, e.g. 5.

> A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].

> A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.

> A boolean array.

Based on that, this may solve your problem:

```py
products = pd.read_csv("priv/products.csv")
product_1 = products.iloc[[0,1]]
```